# Appium Ruby - Can't Scroll To Accessibility_ID

Tags: android, ruby, scroll, appium, appium-desktop

http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/touch/scroll/

I want to scroll to an element. I keep getting an error. Fix may be simple but I'm totally lost.

```
Error: "undefined method `scroll' for #<Appium::TouchAction:0x000055d15d31c980> (NoMethodError)"
```

I am on:

- Linux Mint
- Ruby version 2.5.1p57
- touch_action gem (1.3.3)
- appium_lib gem (10.6.0)
- appium_lib_core gem (3.7.0)

Below is my code.

```
require 'appium_lib'
require 'touch_action'
#require 'selenium-webdriver'

server_url = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"

opts = {
         caps: {
           platformName: :Android,
           platformVersion: 9,
           deviceName: :'Android Emulator',
           app: 'TheApp-v1.9.0.apk',
           newCommandTimeout: 600,
           automationName: :Appium,
           javascript_enabled: true
         }
  }


driver = Appium::Driver.new(opts, true)
driver.start_driver
ta = Appium::TouchAction.new.driver

sleep 5

scroll1 = ta.scroll_to(:accessibility_id, "Verify Phone Number")
scroll1.perform

sleep 2

print "Completed Successfully!"

driver.driver_quit
```

Answer (score 0):

`scroll_to` has historically been flaky in Ruby Appium. I'd suggest writing your own logic similar to the following:

```
ta = Appium::TouchAction.new.driver
swipeUp = ta.swipe(startX, startY, endX, endY, duration)
clicked = false

(0...times).each do
    swipeUp.perform
    unless verifyPhoneNumber.isDisplayed
        verifyPhoneNumber.click
        clicked = true
    end
    break if clicked == true
end
```

My Ruby and Appium are a bit rusty; apologies if there are any errors above, but you should get the gist.

For reusability, I'd probably create a function with this logic that returns the element you were attempting to scroll to.

Comment: My result is "undefined method `swipe' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Comment: You have a problem with your libraries then. It seems unable to create a proper TouchAction. My code was not standalone, it was to be plugged into your framework.

Answer (score 0):

Following Worked for me (solution is for Ruby+Appium+Android)

require 'rubygems'
require 'appium_lib'

```
desired_caps = {
      "appium:deviceName": "055542505S003131",
      "platformName": "android",
      "appium:appPackage": "app.endometriose.android",
      "appium:noReset": true,
      "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
      "appium:appActivity": "host.exp.exponent.MainActivity",
      "app": "/users/user/myApp.apk"
  }

appium_driver = Appium::Driver.new({'caps' => desired_caps, }, true)
 
# Scroll

        appium_driver.scroll_to("Button")
**Note:** scroll_to methods takes visible text of the element and scroll to it.
```